# Critical Points of a smooth map on SO(n)

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

I am given the following map
$f:SO(n) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$f(X) = Tr(DX)$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix $\{d_1,\ldots,d_n\}$, $1<d_1<\cdots <d_n$.

I need to find the critical points of this map, and the index of $f$ at those points.

If I am right, $df = f$ since $f$ is a linear map, but I can not find any critical point.
Do I need to use local charts for $SO(n)$?

Comment: $f$ is critical at a point $p\in SO(n)$ when $ T_p(SO(n))\subset \operatorname{ker} df =\operatorname{ker} f$ where everything is thought of as a subspace of $\Bbb R^{n^2}$. Calculate $\operatorname{ker} f$ and use some stuff you know about $SO(n)$.

Comment: Thank you @PVAL, following your instructions and using that $T_pSO(n) = \{ pA : A = -A^t\}$, I need to find those $p$ which satisfy your relation wrote above; in other words, find $p$ such that $Tr(DpA) = 0$ for every skew-symmetric matrix. However, I do not figure out how to proceed and what stuff about $SO(n)$ I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent space of $M=SO(n)$ at any point $q\in M$ is:
$$T_q(M)=\{xq|x+x^T=0\}$$
Let $df=0$ on $T_q(M)$ we got $Tr(Dxq)=Tr(qDx)=0$ for all skew-symmetric $x$. Let $A=qD$ and let $x_{ij}=-x_{ji}=1$ for fixed $i,j$, and all other entries of $x$ be $0$, $Tr(Ax)=A_{ji}-A_{ij}=0$, we conclude that $A=qD$ is symmetric.
Now $A_{ij}=\sum q_{ik}D_{kj}=q_{ij}d_j=A_{ji}=q_{ji}d_i$, we got $q_{ij}/q_{ji}=d_i/d_j$, so $1=\sum q_{1j}^2=\sum (d_1/d_j)^2 q_{j1}^2\le\sum q_{j1}^2=1$, equality holds if and only if $|q_{11}|=1$ and $q_{1j}=q_{j1}=0, \forall j>1$, thus we conclude $q$ is diagonal with $\pm 1 $ as diagonal elements.